# "Someone of Company" or "Someone from Company"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adjectives

Which one is correct to say?

1. "Hi, it's Jack **of** HP Inc"
2. "Hi, it's Jack **from** HP Inc"

Comment: Why must only one of those be correct?

Comment: Why the downvotes and close? This is exactly the same question that I asked myself today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you used the third person indicates this is a phone conversation. If you were speaking face-to-face then you would say, ""Hi, I'm Jack ..."

In my judgement you would say, "Hi, It's Jack from HP Inc" to indicate where you are calling **from**. You can think of it as saying ""Hi, It's jack [calling] from HP Inc"

If you use "of" then it implies to me that you are not calling from your workplace.

However, in the end, it's more a matter of style than grammar. If forced to make an unequivocal choice, I would favour "from".

Let's see what other opinions there are.

Comment: Other prepositions for indicating an affiliation include *with*, *at*, and more rarely *for*: *Hi, it's Sondra, I'm with Comcast*; *Hi, it's Sondra [over] at Time Warner Cable*; *Hi, it's Sondra, for DIrecTV*.

Answer (score 1):

Both correct. In a phone conversation I might assume the first meant Jack works for HP but may be calling from somewhere else than HP. In the second I would suspect he was calling from an office of HP. But I would not be sure of either.

Answer (score 0):

Each preposition indicates a different kind of relationship with the speaker and their company, and a different intention.  I have never heard example one used by native speakers...only from my students who translate from their own language.  I teach them to say number two as it is the most common way to state your intentions.  I interpret it to mean that the company sent you on business.  We either say it in person or on the telephone.  If we say "with" then we are using the power of association to give our intentions authority (to address choster's comment.)